# Netty server and client timeout

Tags: java, netty

I want to force timeout exception when server is down (for broken network).

I try this configuration:

```
pipeline.addLast("readTimeoutHandler", new ReadTimeoutHandler(5));
pipeline.addLast("writeTimeoutHandler", new WriteTimeoutHandler(5));
// Add the text line codec combination first,
pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));

// Add the encoder and decoder are static as these are sharable
pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());

// Enable stream compression
pipeline.addLast("deflater", new JZlibEncoder(ZlibWrapper.GZIP));
pipeline.addLast("inflater", new JZlibDecoder(ZlibWrapper.GZIP));

pipeline.addLast(clientHandler);
```

but when I shutdown TCP server, the client can try to send message with `channel.writeAndFlush(tempMsg + AbstractSocketInitializer.ESCAPE_CHAR);`

the client never throw exception.

How can I force client to throw exception when try to write in channel and never receive response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look for the `channelInactive` event and act upon it, i.e. throw an exception or something else. In one of the `ChannelInboundHandler`s of your client override the following method:

```
  @Override
public void channelInactive(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
  // do something here
}
```

That method will be triggered as soon as you shutdown your server.